# Diff 2 files ignoring strings between @ and [

Tags: diff

I am comparing two files. I am trying to ignore the alphanumeric characters after `@` and before `[` . A line looks like

```
model.Field@d6b0d6b[fieldName
```

Comment: Can you use `sed` to remove everything between the `@` and `[` characters? If that's the case, you can pipe the output to temporary files, use `diff`, and then know where your changes are. Kind of round-about, but works. Alternatively, you could use Perl.

Comment: How Perl could help ?

Comment: You could write a diff tool in Perl. It wouldn't be too hard, as long as your data is VERY CLOSE to the same.  You would just have to read a line of A and a line of B, then use the Perl `s///` operator to replace everything between `@` and `[` with nothing, and compare the two lines with the `m//` operator. This becomes very complicated very quickly if your data is not VERY similar. (Like if you had to re-syncronize lines.) It's probably easiest for a one-shot deal to just do what I suggested above or what @suspectus suggested below (they are the same thing).

Comment: Please help me in debugging this error "sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unterminated `s' command "

Comment: I suspect your `sed` command is interpreting your unescaped square bracket as the start of a character class. Put `\[` instead of `[`. Take a look at http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html

Comment: i am finding issues in using sed command in perl script . Pleas help

Comment: @PoojaUpadhyaya please accept the answer which helped you to solve this issue so this information can help others. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are **using Bash**.

if `v="model.Field@d6b0d6b[fieldName"` then you can do the following:

```
# Extract the right side of "$v"
r="${v#*[}"
# Extract the left side of "$v"
l="${v%@*}"

# Combine
new_v="$l@[$r"; new_v1="$l$r"
```

You can use **"$new_v"** or **"$new_v1"** depends on whether you want the @ and [ or not.

---

As **Mr. Wijsman** commented, my answer doesn't answer the question. Correct, I did not pay much attention to the title. Let's fix it and wrap the code above with the following function to print a single file's data as required

```
pf()
{
    while read -r line; do
        # This is a bit fancy but does the same thing as the code above.
        printf '%s\n' "${line%@*}${line#*[}"
    done < "$1"
}
```

Now, we can `diff` the two files by using the following command:

```
diff <(pf file1.txt) <(pf file2.txt)
```

Here is a
**Sample output**

```
rany$ cat file1.txt

model.Field1@__A__[fieldName
model.FieldIAMDIFFERENT@__B__[fieldName
model.Field1@__C__[fieldName

rany$ cat file2.txt

model.Field1@__C__[fieldName
model.Field1@__D__[fieldName
model.Field1@__E__[fieldName

rany$ diff <(pf file1.txt) <(pf file2.txt)

2c2
< model.FieldIAMDIFFERENTfieldName
---
> model.Field1fieldName
rany$
```

As you can see, the fact that the lines are different between @ and [ is being ignored, and the only line which is different between the files is this:

**model.FieldIAMDIFFERENTfieldName**

I'm sorry for not paying careful attention to your title as a part of the question.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

I would use [process substitutions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution) here:

```
diff <(sed 's/@[^[]*/@/' old) <(sed 's/@[^[]*/@/' new)
```

Comment: Hi , This really helped but half way The output is : I have occurenece of those characters 2 times , so at the first place they were removed but caught the difference at the second

Comment: com.ibm.dataexplorer.bigindex.search.model.Field@[fieldName=com.ibm.dataexplor                      er.bigindex.search.model.FieldName@4cdc4cdc[fieldName=twitterMsg]
com.ibm.dataexplorer.bigindex.search.model.Field@[fieldName=com.ibm.dataexplor                      er.bigindex.search.model.FieldName@79ff79ff[fieldName=twitterMsg],fieldValues=[c                    om.ibm.dataexplorer.bigindex.internal.search.model.ModifiableFieldValue@4ac84ac8                      [fieldValue=Tweet1]]]

Comment: Pls help me in removing the second occurrence also

Comment: Do you just need to add the "g" flag to the sed "s///" commands?

Answer (score 1):

Filter the datafiles -  then perform diff-:

```
sed 's/\@.*\[/@[/' file1 > file1.filt
sed 's/\@.*\[/@[/' file2 > file2.filt
diff file1.filt file2.filt
```

An alternative is to use `diff` has an option -I . Any lines which match the pattern are ignored in the diff comparision. Select a pattern which will uniquely select the lines which are not to be compared.
e.g.

`diff -I 'dataexplorer.bigindex' file1 file2`

Comment: i have 2 files containing part like com.ibm.dataexplorer.bigindex.search.model.Field@d6b0d6b[fieldName=com.ibm.dataexplorer.bigindex.search.model.FieldName@d700d70[fieldName=twitterMsg]                                           AND i want to do diff of 2 files and it should ignore the characters between @ and [ because these will change on every new run and hence my diff will not  pass

Comment: does `diff -I ...` help?

Comment: Hi I tried using sed but i got this sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unterminated `s' command
 pls explain whta is the cause My expression was  $rc = systemTestSetup::execute("sed 's/\@.*\[/@[/' $tmpDir/data/actual_out.tmp > $tmpDir/data/actual_out");

Comment: diff -I ? how it could be used ?

Comment: Please help me in debugging this error "sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unterminated `s' command "

Comment: Please help me by giving me the information I need to help you. What sed command are you running?

Comment: I am running this cmd $rc = systemTestSetup::execute("sed 's/\@.*\[/@[/' $tmpDir/data/actual_out.tmp > $tmpDir/data/actual_out");

Comment: What is the command you normally run (systemTestSetup) without any sed command?

Comment: i am using this sed command in perl script , so systemTestSetup is beig used to execute or run the cmd

Comment: like later in my program i m comparing 2 files $rc = systemTestSetup::execute("diff -b $tmpDir/data/actual_out.tmp $expectedfile");

Comment: Can I use sed command in perl script ??

Comment: Yes - `system()` is the perl function to do this.

Comment: Don't use `sed` in perl. Use `s/thingToFind/thingToReplaceItWith/`. You'll be much happier. http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/sandtr.html